# Saving a 3ware RAID configuration for later use?

Tags: linux, raid, 3ware

I have a 3ware-based (using tw_cli) 24-bay array filled with 2 TB hard drives, used for backup. The plan is to upgrade them to substantially larger drives, but I would like to remove the 2 TB drives and label them so that if the upgrade fails for any reason, I can put the 2 TB drives back in and resume as normal.

The array is unmounted, but for reasons out of my control I cannot down the server during this operation. Is there any way to save the configuration of the array to a file, safely remove the drives, and if necessary at a future time put the drives back into the array in the same order and restore the configuration? The server will remain the same during the entire procedure, so if I need to put the old array back in, it will be under nearly identical conditions, including the same controller, same tw_cli version, same OS version, et al.

If the above is not quite feasible as described, would I have a high chance of success if I dumped "/cx show" to a file and then manually recreated the setup from those contents? Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of here? I'd also be fine with a "the disks have metadata, and the controller will just automagically work it out when you put everything back" answer, but I'm not certain how to verify that this is the case with my setup.

Further details:

- CLI Version = 2.00.11.016
- API Version = 2.08.00.017
- Controller = 9750-24i4e
- OS = openSUSE Leap 42.2

Comment: In MOST cases the array configuration is stored on all member disks, but hopefully someone can give a solid answer. On Dell is referred to as "import foreign config"